# Can't figure out logic proof

Tags: logic

I have this logic proof for a class that I can't get past: $A\to C\vdash A\to(E\to C)$.

Note: $\to$ means implies. I've already fiddled with material implication and transposition but it's not going anywhere.

Comment: What does the slash mean?  Do you mean how to get from $A \Rightarrow C$ to $A \Rightarrow (E \Rightarrow C)$ for arbitrary $E$?

Comment: It separates the premise and the conclusion, the premise being A>C.

Comment: So basically yes

Comment: Assume A.  Then C (given $A\to C$).  From C we have then $\lnot E \lor C$ (Or introduction).  From $\lnot E \lor C $ we have the equivalent $E\to C$.  Hence, If $A$, then $(E\to C)$. I.e,. $A \to (E\to C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By Natural Deduction:** The premise is $A\to C$.   So if we assume $A$ and further assume $E$, then $C$ is derived by *modus ponens* (aka the conditional elimination rule).   Discharging those assumptions deduces (via the conditional introduction rule) $A\to(E\to C)$ , as was required.

**By rules of replacement and implication:** The basis is that anything will implie a truth (ie $X\to Y$ is true if $Y$ is true).   So  $A\to C$ implies $E\to (A\to C)$, and from there you may use exportation and importation rules (if you know them, or by using the implication equivalence rule and association and commutation rules for disjunction).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** "Implies" is a loaded term in English.  For your problem, you can interpret $A \Rightarrow C$ as simply "$C$ is true whenever $A$ is; $C$ can only be false if $A$ is also."

If you were to look at it in graphical terms, $A$ would be a circle that is wholly within the circle representing $C$.  In the conclusion, everything in the parentheses is operating in the domain inside the circle representing $A$.  Is $C$ *ever* false in there?

Comment: C is never false if E is true but could be either true or false if E is false.

Comment: C could be false if A were false or if E were false or both but if A and E were both true then C would necessarily be true as well.

Comment: So how do I prove it using the rules of replacement and the rules of implication?

Comment: Hint: $\neg A\vee C$ implies $\neg E\vee(\neg A\vee C)$ @TorTrombeck

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I needed